# Worksheet flickers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new with VBA, so I'm trying to create a macro button that can copy paste data from one worksheet to another but I think my code is flawed because the worksheet flickers whenever I run the code

tried a simple code since I'm new with VBA

```
Worksheets("Survey Form").Range("C9").Copy
Worksheets("Database").Activate
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Survey Form").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I want the code to run smoothly without that flicker

Comment: Get rid of all the `.Select` and `.Activate` see here how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: `Worksheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Worksheets("Survey Form").Range("C9").Value` Is all you need. and it will not flicker.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Thank you so much for your help it solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was suggested in the comments, you should also try this:

```
Sub something()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
'
'the rest of your code here
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This should actually make your code run both smoother and faster.